# Setuptools never found on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-lambda

I'm attempting to use AWS Lambda to do some python package introspection.

What I'm trying to do is, on a git push, checkout a package, install its dependencies (the package dependencies are required for introspection), and run the tooling. AWS does not by default have pip installed (you're supposed to bundle your own dependencies)--so I bundle pip in with my lambda function.

Every other part of my lambda works, except for trying to install package dependencies. When attempting to use my bundled pip with the checked-out package, it fails trying to run setuptools:

```
Collecting alembic==0.8.3 (from -r /tmp/tmpnx0tY0/requirements.txt (line 1)) 
Downloading alembic-0.8.3.tar.gz (935kB) 
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
ImportError: No module named setuptools 
 ---------------------------------------- 
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/tmp30m2KN/alembic
```

I've tried everything: add the current path (with setuptools) to path, copy setuptools to the temp directory, run `pip install setuptools`, passing options using `--global-options`, tried to `pOpen` with an env specifying `PYTHONPATH`, even tried to use older versions of pip with: `pip install -r requirements.txt --download --no-install`. Nothing seems to work.

How can I get this `python setup.py egg_info` call to successfully locate setuptools?

Comment: So you are trying to install pip packages in Lambda during runtime of the function?

Comment: @birnbaum Yes. Because this introspection may pull in any number of software packages, I can't know which dependencies I need ahead of time. The solution is to install at runtime, but I'm running into this issue when I try to.

Comment: Did you include just pip with your lambda, or you packaged an entire virtualenv directory structure with it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Jenkins (or any other CI tool) to hook into your Git repository,  build the repository on push and then upload the packaged lambda with all dependencies to S3 before running it?

Within AWS Lambdas, you can only download files to the /tmp folder and you have a limit of 50mb of space. This 50mb includes the space consumed by your lambda function also. Lambdas are zipped and don't contain pip for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I used Lambda for a bit and I don't think Lambda supports that. You need to use your own CI tools(Jenkins is a good choice). Otherwise, You need to build it on your local then use AWS Lambda plugin to upload your code with dependencies installed.